# I am trying to build services using scrutor

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

This is my code,

```
 builder.Services.Scan(scan => scan
.FromAssemblyDependencies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
.AddClasses(classes =>
    classes.AssignableTo<IBrandTypeClient>())
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.WithTransientLifetime());
```

give me this 500 error`

Unable to resolve service for type 'BravoBrand_WebApiVersion.Provider.Interface.IBrandTypeProvider' while attempting to activate 'BravoBrand_WebApiVersion.Controllers.BrandTypeController'.

Comment: I can't find any code about `FromAssemblyDependencies`, please try to use [FromAssemblies.](https://github.com/snatch-dev/Convey/blob/6f7374ad6e1f4d902757aa3de4b991d236a762a6/src/Convey.CQRS.Events/src/Convey.CQRS.Events/Extensions.cs#L13)